# Ingress-Nginx on Azure Kubernetes Cluster always routes to a 404 page

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

When applying the yaml file to the ingress services a load balancer is created. I pointed my DNS domain to that load balancer IP and it reaches the nginx server. However when routing to https://www.example.com/api/users/ or https://www.example.com/api/users/currentuser/ (or it's http:// equivalents) it returns a 404 page. Here is the Ingress-Nginx yaml file I'm using:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: be-auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 9001
          - path: /auth/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: be-contact-form-srv
                port:
                  number: 9000
```

Anybody can shed light on this topic? Thanks

Comment: have you actually fully set up TLS? if not, I'd suggest you start by just using HTTP without TLS, just to verify your routing setup.

Comment: with http routes results in the same behaviour if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example you provided, I would suggest, as a test, to update the first path definition to the following:

- path: /api/users(/|$)(.*)

...and assuming the Nginx Ingress Controller is already configured to terminate TLS, try reaching https://www.example.com/api/users/

I would also double check that the be-auth-srv service is configured to listen on port 9001.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing ingress-nginx in the AKS environment using yaml file in Azure Powershell.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start